# Silverlight Layout Grid Child Controls

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to set properties of buttons inside of a layout grid.  The grid itself is dynamically generated and so are the buttons inside of the grid cells.  Unfortunately I cannot reference anything by name in code.

I need to refernce the buttons based on the grid cell they are in.  I tried using the following code.

```
 stackButton = (Button) (from buttons in rowGrid.Children
                          where Grid.GetColumn (buttons as FrameworkElement) == s.RoomCol
                          where Grid.GetRow (buttons as FrameworkElement) == s.RoomRow
                          select buttons).FirstOrDefault();
```

The "stackButton" control is a Button control.  "s" is a custom control that holds coordinates for the button within the grid.  I do not get any objects returned when that code executes. Any ideas how I can better execute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Not without getting creative (see below). That's basically the only way because of how attached properties work.

**Aside**

Two things though... stylistically, instead of two where clauses, you can use &&
You can technically have two controls share the same row/column (in which case they are superimposed, so you may want to rethink "firstordefault"

**Full answer: YES**

If you wanted to get super clever, you could register your own attached dependency properties like: `Grid.MyRow` and `Grid.MyColumn` and give them an `OnChanged` handler, which would:

- set the standard `Grid.SetRow` (or column)
- add your control to a dictionary, keyed with row, column. ie: make your own class that has `Row` and `Column`, implement `Equals`, and `GetHashCode`, so you can do this:

  Dictionary _buttons = new Dictionary();

  OnChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     // snip
     _dict.Add(new GridKey(row, column), button);
  }

Then your lookup becomes a O(1) operation instead of O(n)

If you don't want to go the attached properties route, you can simply do the _dict.Add thing when you dynamically generate the grid. (when you do `rowGrid.Children.Add(..)`)

If you can't do that, then you can have a method which iterates through the children once and adds them all to the dictionary, so that further lookups are O(1)

Comment: does this answer your question?